# Set css based on toggle screen window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I would like to set conditional css based on the inner screen size when the screen toggle mode is on.

Scenario :

1. By default the left panel will be in collapsed state with toggle classes active as `span3` and `span9`.
2. When `Sidebar Toggle1` is clicked classes `span0` and `span12` gets activated.

Based on active class I would like to make the buttons to appear one below another by applying class `display-inline`

I'm not able to identify the inner screen size before collapsing and after collapsing.Is there any way to identify the width ?If in that case i can set css based on that width using media query.

```
$('#trig').on('click', function () {
    $('#colMain').toggleClass('span12 span9');
    $('#colPush').toggleClass('span0 span3');
});
```

Fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/14nqvuya/)

Comment: Why do you think you need to check for any width here? Your container has a specific class in this situation, so all you need to do is format the buttons differently based on that in your stylesheet ...

Comment: @CBroe how can I identify using jquery/css that a specific class is created?So that I can modify the buttons.

Comment: You don't need to identify "creation" of anything here ... you simply need to _have_ a rule in your stylesheet that applies the desired formatting to the elements when there happens to be an element with that class. If there isn't, then that rule simply doesn't match anything ...